# Downloading xml data on very slow 2G internet

Tags: java, android, xml

i have successfully programmed an app that takes Traces of allot of system services (GPS location, Network Location, wifi, neighbouringcellinfo, sensors ....) in every 10 seconds which works very well, but as soon as i restrict the internet on my phone to use only 2G and turn off Wifi i get the app still works but start to lag.

I have tried to find out where the Problem is coming from and i have noticed that it comes from this code line:

```
XmlPullParser receivedData = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
                    .newPullParser().setInput(xmlUrl.openStream(), null); return receivedData;
```

As soon as i delete this couple of code lines in my activity the app works without lagging, but seeing as they are essential for my app i would very much like to have them work (which they already do) but without causing lags.

Can anyone please help me?

I have printed the parsed result from the XML file and it is correct, so my only problem here is the lagging of the app.

A typical XML file that i would be dealing with looks like this:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<cell lat="49.88415658974359" lon="8.637537076923078" mcc="262" mnc="7" lac="41146" 
cellid="42404" averageSignalStrength="-79" samples="39" changeable="1"/>
</rsp>
```

Comment: Which size is the XML? Can you load the file in a background Thread?

Comment: You could try first to transfer the data gzip compressed (GZipInput/OutputStream).

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach i have added an example of the a typical xml file that i am dealing with, but the file does get downloaded so i'm guessing that the problem is the lag and the internet activity that would cause a freeze.

Comment: @JoopEggen can you please clarify with a code fragment of what it is you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2g is some really slow connection. Even worse is the "warm up" of the antenna. It may last up to 30 seconds, before teh first bit is received. (And there is not really something you can do against this, because it is all about physics).

So the only thing you could do is loading the File in an background-Thread. This will make the appp resonsive (if yo don't need the data in time).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, in my case i would unfortunately require the data in real-time.
Do you know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

***Mayb explicitly a BufferedInputStream***

```
XmlPullParser receivedData = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
                .newPullParser().setInput(xmlUrl.openStream(), null);

XmlPullParser receivedData = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
                .newPullParser().setInput(
                    new BufferedInputStream(xmlUrl.openStream()), null);
```

---

***Maybe, maybe compression***

As you know in HTTP a browser may declare in its headers that it can [decompress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) compressed data; and then the server may send a compressed version of the HTML. This serves to put less load on the server side, and *may* speed up communication, depending.

The same one can do oneself.

For an external uncontrolled site one might try. Send a header

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

And one is lucky when receiving a response header:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Doing boing sides oneselfby wrapping the streams:

```
outputStream = new GZipOutputStream(outputStream);

inputStream = new GZipImüputStream(inputStream);
```

---

***Saving memory***
To make the same string instancees unique reduces memory and might help, even if it costs considerable time itself. `String.intern()` is bad idea, as prior to java 8, the strings go into the permanent (unrecoverable) memory space. One might use a

```
private Map<String, String> identityMap = new HashMap<>();

public String unique(String s) {
    if (s.length() >= 30) {
        return s;
    }
    String t = identityMap.get(s);
    if (t == null) {
        t = s;
        identityMap.put(s, t);
    }
    return t;
}
```

The hope is, that processing becomes faster.